# AWS RoR - Not Storing Photos as Medium; but rather, Original

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip

When integrating my RoR application with AWS to store a user's Facebook photo, the photo is stored as "original" rather than "medium".

Here is the relevant information from my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :avatar,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :style => {:medium => "370x370", :thumb => "100x100"}

    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Calling the original photo is successful, but I need the medium thumbnail, because displaying the photo as original presents an aesthetic issue.

Here is the relevant information from my `_user.html.erb` user file:

```
<div class="img"><%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:original), height: "370", width: "370" %> </div>
```

however, like I said, I do not want to put original, I would like to call the file from AWS, like so:

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:medium)
```

When I inspect the page, I see that ":medium" it is not being saved, so I would assume this is a problem with the model user.rb, but any and all help is greatly appreciated, as I've been stuck on this issue for quite some time.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Paperclip, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to first set the validator. I think PaperClip cares about the image size. So in your model:

```
validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, :attributes => :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes
```

That worked for me.